# Speed Up IIS7 FTP+SSL Transfers

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl, ftp, upload

I am currently using a Server 2008 R2 box with IIS 7.5. I have IIS FTP+SSL setup and working properly with AD accounts. My issue lies in upload speeds. On a previous unix host FTP transfers were quick both with large files, and small files in any quantity. With IIS FTP once a transfer of a specific file starts, the transfer rate is fine, however the transfer of many files takes a LONG time, it seems to go through many FTP steps.

Here is what happens with each file to be moved (Client in Cyberduck on OS X):

```
LIST -a
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
-rwxrwxrwx   1 owner    group              19 Feb 16  9:04 file.php
226 Transfer complete.
NOOP
200 NOOP command successful.
CWD /dir1/dir2
250 CWD command successful.
TYPE A
200 Type set to A.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,219,249).
```

(x,x,x,x) is the server IP

It took about 60 seconds for 42 files totaling 3.1 MB over LAN.

Any ideas on how to speed up FTP?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using different FTP software. Specifically Panic.com's Transmit allowed for greatly increased transfer speeds. Not sure what if different in how Transmit handles the FTP+SSL protocol, but it does the trick.